com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 8502: SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE
Hello in the below going to failure condition with exception case.Calling below method to show location popup but it is giving an exception.
Can any one help me how to resolve this. Every time going to failure block without any exception
public void requestDeviceLocationSettings(Activity activity) {
        LocationRequest.Builder locationRequest = new LocationRequest.Builder(Priority.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
        LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
                .addLocationRequest(locationRequest.build());
        builder.setAlwaysShow(true);
        Task<LocationSettingsResponse> task =
                LocationServices.getSettingsClient(activity).checkLocationSettings(builder.build());


        task.addOnSuccessListener(activity, new OnSuccessListener<LocationSettingsResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LocationSettingsResponse locationSettingsResponse) {
                Log.d("jyothi",""+locationSettingsResponse);
                if(hasPermissions(activity)) {
                    locationPermissionResult(1);
                    bluetoothPermissionResult(PesConstants.BLE_ENABLED);
                } else {
                    requestLocationPermission(activity);
                }

            }
        });

        task.addOnFailureListener(activity, new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Log.d("jyothi",""+e);
                if (e instanceof ResolvableApiException) {
                    // Location settings are not satisfied, but this can be fixed
                    // by showing the user a dialog.
                    try {
                        // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(),
                        // and check the result in onActivityResult().
                        ResolvableApiException resolvable = (ResolvableApiException) e;
                        resolvable.startResolutionForResult(activity,
                                Constant.REQUEST_CHECK_LOCATION_SETTINGS);

                    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException sendEx) {
                        // Ignore the error.
                    }
                    //displayLocationAlert(activity);
                }
            }
        });

    }

